# creating logging for django rest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a logger for my application.
It should create a file `day wise` and if the file size is cross `100MB` it will create a new file for that
this is my **logger_config.py**

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Use a TimedRotatingFileHandler to log to a file that rotates every day
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('loggerFiles', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=30)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Logging levels
logger.debug("This is a debug message")
logger.info("This is an info message")
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
logger.error("This is an error message")

import os
filepath = None
def check_log_file_size(filepath):
    """
    Check if the log file has exceeded the maximum size
    """
    size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    if size > 100000000: # 100000000 bytes = 100MB
        new_filepath = f'{filepath}_1'
        os.rename(filepath, new_filepath)
```

that is how I'm using it.

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            # some code that may raise an exception
            1/0
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("An exception occurred: %s", e)
            return Response({"error": "An exception occurred"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but the problem is it is not creating fils as I want.

Comment: I think this code should be placed in project `settings.py`

Comment: I have Added _[this code in setting](https://linkode.org/#PyDZ3LsJKP5pwf56enL1E5)

Comment: Unless you're somehow very constrained or in specific circumstances, it's usually a better idea to use an external log rotation service on your server, instead of letting your app worry about log rotation. It simplifies the app responsibilities and allows the server admin to manage log files as they see fit without needing to change the application code.